# Count each repeated value mysql result array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search

I would like to count all the repeated values in a mysql result array. For example

```
array (
[0] = > array (
 ["id"] => 1
["n"] => "ab"
)
[1] = > array (
 ["id"] => 5
["n"] => "bc"
)
[2] = > array (
 ["id"] => 4
["n"] => "cd"
)
[3] = > array (
 ["id"] => 1
["n"] => "ef"
)
)
```

So, taking the multidemensional array above, I want to count the amount of times each value of id is repeated in the array.

The result would be

```
1 = 2 times
5 = 1 time
4 = 1 time
```

I know I can do this with the array_search() function, but in my case, I don't know what i'm searching for. I just need the amount of results that have a specific repeated value.

Comment: be easy with a foreach loop, but there are other ways

Comment: @Dagon Please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, using `foreach` loop:

```
$final = array();
foreach($array as $ar)
    $final[$ar["id"]] = isset($final[$ar["id"]]) ? $final[$ar["id"]] + 1 : 1;
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [5]=>
  int(1)
  [4]=>
  int(1)
}
```

[**Demonstration**](https://eval.in/387249)

Comment: In my case, the values that are repeated aren't only numbers. They're random strings similar to an md5 hash with both number and letters. Would this still work?

Comment: @user4559334: Yes, it will

Comment: I get the following error: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

Comment: nevermind. It works. There was a small error on my part

Comment: One last question, how do I go through this resulting array and work with each value? $final[0] returns null

Comment: @user4559334: Well, you can use `foreach` to iterate through `$final` array too.

Comment: For reference the var_ dump looks like this  array(2) { ["559551b78f154a04427b41d16d8614c8a855"]=> int(2) ["4953c1d7c87e1d51ead026ee4e304ae3cb49"]=> int(1) }

Comment: @user4559334: these are your keys, you can access array elements with it like `$final["559551b78f154a04427b41d16d8614c8a855"]`. It is not fancy, but as long as you are using hashed values it is the option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
$array = array ( 0 => array("id" => 1, "n" => "ab"), 1 => array("id" => 5, "n" => "bc"), 2 => array("id" => 4, "n" => "cd"), 3 => array("id" => 1, "n" => "ef"));
$counts = array_count_values(array_column($array, "id"));
print_r($counts);
```